# How do different static readonly property implementations (vs fields) behave in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, language-lawyer

Wanted to ask a couple of questions regarding how the .NET platform handles static variables during runtime, in its inner workings.

Note: This is for educational purposes, and *not* due to performance concerns.

Considering the three variable definitions below:

```
using System;

public static class UserProperties
{
    public static Guid UserId1 { get { return new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"); } }

    public static Guid UserId2 { get; } = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");

    public static readonly Guid UserId3 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
}
```

First: As I understand it, there is a benefit in using `UserId2` over `UserId1`, as it does not instantiate a new `Guid` everytime the property is accessed, but instead assigns a single instantiation to a backing field that is maintained for as long as the program is running. Is this understanding correct?

Second: Is there any benefit in using `UserId3` over `UserId2`? I suspect there would be, since the former is a itself a field and the latter is an auto property that *I think* does a method call everytime it's referred to, but I'm unsure about that.

And last: If there are, indeed, differences <sub>(which yes, are negligible in this particular example, but still)</sub>, are they rendered non-existant by optimization - i.e. does the compiler or JIT give out the exact same instructions?

Thanks!

Comment: p.s. Couldn't come up with a better title; anyone feel free to offer suggestions.

Comment: Your understanding looks correct. As for optimizations - first one cannot be reduced to the others, since it returns new Guid instance on every call. Second however will likely be inlined by JIT compiler (on every call site) to be the same as third. Most important difference between 2 and 3 is that 2 allows you to later change the logic of getter without breaking (third party) code using it. On 3 there is no "getter" so no way to do that without changing from field to property (breaking change).

Comment: In a release build, `UserId2` will be inline into the same as `UserId3` so no difference

Comment: Why not compare apples to apples and do `return Guid.Parse();`?